# how to extract text from scanned documents using python

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, stanford-nlp, tesseract

I tried this example, https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract

```
import Image
import pytesseract

print pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('image1.png'))
```

Getting error:
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child raise child_exception OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Is there any other way to extract text from scanned document?

Comment: What's wrong with that way?

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: getting this errors

Comment: How did you install pytesseract?  Did you use pip?  What's your OS?  Looks like linux from the stack trace?  Those would all be helpful things to know in diagnosing this problem.

Comment: yes ubuntu 14.04 and installed it using pip

Comment: What's on line 1327 of "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py"?

Comment: try:
                    _eintr_retry_call(os.waitpid, self.pid, 0)
                except OSError as e:
                    if e.errno != errno.ECHILD:
                        raise
                child_exception = pickle.loads(data)
line1327: raise child_exception

Comment: What is the file or directory that it isn't finding?  (Should be something like No such file or directory: ***)

Comment: that file is present in same folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141538/discussion-between-gaw89-and-vikrant).

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue,

updated :

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py

tesseract_cmd = 'tesseract' =====>> tesseract_cmd = '/usr/local/bin/tesseract'
```

And now its working.

Comment: This is weird, `/usr/local/bin` should be in your search path by default.

Comment: i tried this but accuracy is less, any other package available for same functionality.

Answer (score -2):

use below command

sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr

Comment: From the traceback and following discussion, you can see that the problem was not related at all with `PIL`/`pillow`.